# How to understand which words or phrase brackets point to?

Tags: phrase-meaning, punctuation

#### Example showing how brackets can be confusing

This is a sample from [an O' Level science book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Edexcel-IGCSE-Chemistry-Student-International/dp/0435966898):

> The impure solid is dissolved in the minimum amount of hot water (or any other suitable solvent) [...]

There are two ways to interpret this:

1. *Hot water* (as a whole) is one "suitable solvent", but any other such solvents can used. **The solid is to be dissolved in *a suitable solvent*.**
2. *Water* is a "suitable solvent"; other solvents can also be used. Whatever the solvent is, it has to be *hot*. **The solid is to be dissolved in a *hot solvent*.**

Since this is a science book, the writers have to state the reasons behind everything and ensure clarity. The following sentences (indirectly) clear up the confusion:

> [...], and then allowed to cool again. Most solids are less soluble in
>   the cold than in the hot, and so crystals are formed again.

So #2 was the right interpretation.

#### The question

However, in most unscientific day-to-day writing, not every sentence has to be backed up by explanation. So the question is
**how to understand which word(s) or phrase brackets point to?**

Comment: There is nothing grammatical that can distinguish those two interpretations, at least without modifications to the sentence. You have to rely (as you ably did) on context, reasoning, and what you know about the world. It's worth noting that even if you hadn't had the following sentences, you would ask yourself: If the heat has nothing to do with the water's quality as a solvent, why would they specify "hot"? If you give the authors the benefit of the doubt, you would proceed on the assumption that the heat *is* relevant.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I'm a non-native speaker (and only a 8th grader). It isn't always that easy for me. Not everything is as obvious to me.

Comment: 8th-grader or not, you did a good job of reasoning your way through the passage. You'll encounter many more of these ambiguous sentences, and you can continue to deal with them the same way you dealt with this one. It's a good question — sorry there isn't a satisfying answer!

Comment: @LukeSawczak Thanks for giving your opinion, anyways. So, there's really no hard and fast rule? And I like asking intriguing questions on problems like this, which probably many people face.

Comment: I'd read *hot water* as a single block in that example (your interpretation #1). Presumably, *cold* water wouldn't be a *suitable solvent*. The word *suitable* seems to be significant here. However, other words in other contexts might favour your interpretation #2. As @LukeSawczak notes, this is part of the ambiguity of language - certainly in English, but also, I'd expect, in other natural languages as well.

Comment: I think it's stretching a point to assume *#2 was the right interpretation*. It's true that water is called a "universal solvent". But *in general* people tend to think of "typical" solvents as being volatile (often, *flammable*) liquids that it would be dangerous and/or inconvenient to use hot. And don't forget things like the [Liquid Carbon Dioxide Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decaffeination) used to decaffeinate coffee beans, where the concept of "hot solvent" seems inappropriate. Personally I'd say #1 is the obvious default interpretation here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had the same default interpretation, but like your reading, it was reasoned out from my very basic understanding of chemistry and not a deeper understanding of crystallization - in neither case from anything inherent to the English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two interpretations are both grammatically possible and your description of the differences in meaning is absolutely right. Since you came to the right conclusion, the rest of this answer is probably spelling out what you already know, but it might be helpful to someone else with similar problems. After all, we all encounter ambiguous sentences like this every day...

To answer the question directly: No, nothing forces "or other suitable solvent" to apply to either "water" or "hot water". In this case, the rules of evaluation don't bind either pair of items more closely.

Simply reasoning about it, you might say: "If all that mattered was that it was water, they wouldn't have called the water *hot*."

> ... the minimum of [ [ hot water ] or other suitable solvent ]

But as you noted, we can hold off on applying "hot" until we've evaluated the next expression, and it can still make sense because solvents can be hot:

> ...the minimum amount of [ hot [ water or other suitable solvent ] ]
>   
> → ... the minimum amount of hot solvent

So you move on to what you know about the world. According to the above reading, one needs a hot solvent to dissolve the impure solid. Now, based on what you've learned so far about solvents, are they generally more effective if they're hot, or is that only true of water? You might conclude that it's the water that needs to be hot, because many solvents are more effective than water at any temperature...

However, once you consider that the subject is crystallization, you discover that the temperature of the solvent *is* relevant for this particular application. Of course, the catch-22 is that this is the very subject you're learning about right now, so you're *not* likely to know this already. So you may have to quickly add to your knowledge of the world with [a search result](http://www.foothill.edu/psme/armstrong/recrystallization.shtml) or two.

Even if you stopped there, you probably have enough certainty to proceed on the assumption that "hot solvent" is correct and not "hot water". But luckily this whole limbo of assumption doesn't last long, because you're reading a sentence out of a whole chapter — and context, which is your strongest tool, allows the author to clarify what they mean. As people usually do in life. :)

---

*Edit:* That this sort of ambiguity is inherent in all languages and difficult to resolve is demonstrated very well by [David Bellos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Bellos) in [*Is That a Fish in Your Ear?*](https://www.amazon.ca/That-Fish-Your-Ear-Translation/dp/0865478767), his book on translation:

> An EU regulation exists that allows member states to make exemptions from the general rule for the 'transport of animal carcasses or waste not intended for human consumption'. [A] firm that had been fined in the UK had been transporting animal carcasses *to butcher's shops*, which clearly intended to sell them for human consumption. But the lorry firm claimed it was exempted from the rule by the EU clause just quoted [...] The lorry firm's lawyers claimed that waste not intended for human consumption and animal carcasses in general (whether intended for human consumption or not) were exempted, where as the UK courts had considered that the exemption only applied to waste and animal carcasses NOT intended for human consumption. [...]
>
> **The issue at the heart of this case is a familiar problem in the language of law and in language in general: when you have a list of nouns followed by a qualifying or restricting phrase, where do you put the brackets? Does the restricting phrase restrict every member of the list, or only the last one?** Does the expression 'children and women with babes in arms' include children with babes in arms or does it not?
>
> **In daily usage we leave disambiguation of this kind to common sense and context.**
>   
> <sub>(pp.246–7)</sub>

He goes on to describe how the court examined all 23 versions of the exemption in the different languages of the EU, and found only one (Dutch) where the restriction "not intended for human consumption" unambiguously applied to both "animals" and "waste". This was taken as the authoritative version, and the firm had to pay the fine.

The syntax of this example isn't identical to the one you cited, but it's the same problem at its core. How can you know what a modifier applies to? Apparently you shouldn't ask the European Court of Justice. (Incidentally, I think common sense would have been sufficient if it weren't a legal case: if "not intended for human consumption" only applied to "waste", why would they even mention it? Is there any animal waste that *is* intended for human consumption? But in law you must be sure!)

By the way, it's worth noting that this kind of ambiguity is quite easy to avoid orally. Your intonation, pause points, and even stress generally give strong hints as to what applies to what. For instance, in @Tᴚoɯɐuo's example about "breast milk (or formula)", the term "breast milk" is a compound noun rather than an adjective + noun and hence must be stressed on the first syllable, which signals to the listener that "breast" cannot apply to "formula".

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine I've added a passage in support of this analysis that might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The parenthetic remark normally immediately follows the word(s) it  refers to.

> Add two tsp sugar (or honey).
>
> Add two tsp sugar (or molasses to taste).  <sup>not necessarily 2 tsp molasses</sup>
>
> Add 2 oz apple (or red wine) vinegar.

If the authors wanted to qualify *hot*, the parenthetic remark would follow the adjective.

> Dissolve the powder in warm (or boiling) water.

Coming after "hot water", the parenthetic remark qualifies the noun phrase, "hot water".

> Dissolve the powder in hot water (or whiskey).

The whiskey need not be hot. It is an alternative to hot water.

This is a well-established typographic/orthographic convention.

Comment: Feed the baby warm milk (or formula).

Comment: Nutritional value may vary depending on food, but none is as complete as breast milk (or formula).

Comment: Precisely. Hopefully through these two contrasting examples one can come to the conclusion that it's not a typographic convention but a deduction on the basis of the context and the sense produced by the different applications of the modifier.

Comment: -1 You didn't quite get the thing.

Comment: @Soha Farhin Pine:  This is an issue of information packaging. since the grammar is ambiguous. In a chemistry textbook, say, the phrase  **Hot water (or alcohol)**  would normally not indicate that the alcohol must be hot. However, in a cookbook, **pureed strawberries (or lingonberries)** would probably indicate that the lingonberries should be pureed as well.  If we wanted to say that the alcohol needed to be hot too, we wouldn't write it that way but like this:  **...in hot water or hot alcohol** or like this: **... in water or alcohol; whichever solvent is chosen, it should be heated.**

Comment: The degree of specificity will depend on what  level of basic knowledge and "common sense" the author can assume for the readership.  If the alcohol doesn't need to be heated, the chemistry textbook would probably rely on the typographic convention **in hot water (or alcohol)** to indicate that **alcohol** is an alternative to **hot water**.  If it is critical that the alcohol be heated (perhaps the reaction will fail if it is not) then we'd probably find **in hot water or hot alcohol** or the other more elaborate instruction about it needing to be heated.

Comment: Indeed: such a clarification would be made when the reader's depth of knowledge can't be assumed because, again, the text itself and its conventions are not internally able to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: @LukeSawczak and T o uo -- *hot water (or any other suitable solvent)* -- looking at it strictly from a grammar point of view, I should think that the adjective 'hot' has no reason to be applied to what's within the brackets that come after the noun it describes -- although the sentences that follow it seem to indicate that was what the textbook writer intended! (Now a statement like *'dissolve it in hot water or milk'* would be genuinely ambiguous.) This is a technical error by the writer from an English point of view, and no mistake of OP, who did actually interpret it correctly in context.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an error however technically we analyze it. It's certainly an oversight in terms of clarity. But the brackets unfortunately don't change the ambiguous range of application, and it's easy to construct examples where a modifier definitely applies to what's within the brackets. I'd like it to be systematic, but I don't think it is.